# Need help with .htaccess ReWrite rules

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I'm using Wordpress and have the following pemalink `/%category%/%postname%`.
This gives me user friendly URLs like *http://www.example.com/something/*.

With this permalink, I will not be able to access php files directly, e.g. *http://www.example.com/something/myfile.php*.

I need to write a ReWrite rule which allows me access to */include/myfile.php*.
Can some help me please? :)

Here's my current .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myblogdirectory/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /myblogdirectory/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**Update**

Ok, I got it working.

I was doing it wrong from the start. I was using the "virtual" path instead of the physical path.

Instead of /mysite/includes/myfile.php, I have to use /wp-content/themes/mytheme/include/myfile.php

I could probably also have added RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !myfile.php, which would have excluded myfile.php from the rewrite rules. I have not tested this though.

Comment: Try some debugging with mod_rewrite’s logging (see RewriteLogLevel).

Comment: Done. Updated above text

Comment: According to the log, `/include` is not a directory. Or is it?

Comment: /include/ is a directory, yes. I found the problem (se answer above). I also, after diging around, found that I probably could have used RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !myfile.php, to exclude that file from the rewrite rules.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your rewrite rules looks good.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

means that /blog/index.php won't be serverd if %{REQUEST_FILENAME] is a physical file or directory.

More info [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond).

Are you sure that you're using the correct file paths?

The file you want to request should be located in /blog/include/myfile.php.

Check your error.log for apache for any related messages.

Comment: But doesn't it say that "The base for these rules are for /myblogdirectory/". If a whatever.php file is requested, foward request to /myblogdirectory/index.php" ? (I've updated the code to.)

Comment: PS. This is a good article about understanding Wordpress Permalinks: http://www.homebizpal.com/blogging/wordpress/understanding-wordpress-permalinks/